# Email restriction based on date range not working using Python

Tags: python, outlook

I'm trying to run a function that will only show the subject of unread emails with a date restriction. When I try to run the below code in Python, it's still showing unread emails dated two weeks back.

```
import win32com.client
import pythoncom
import json
import os
from datetime import date, timedelta
import datetime as dt

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items

for message in messages:
    if message.Unread == True:
        lastWeekDateTime = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days = 7)
        lastWeekDateTime = lastWeekDateTime.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')
        message = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + lastWeekDateTime +"'")
        print(messages.subject)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even I was facing the issue today and found that it is because of date format.

I changed format to "lastDay.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M %p')+"'")" and it worked as per the expectations.

Hope his helps you

[image]

Comment: Thanks for providing the above answer. Now works as needed